# Create custom .OBJ / .MTL file and render it with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, export, blender

I tried to create a simple blender model, export it to .obj/.mtl and render it with three.js. But something doesn't work. I downloaded (and uploaded) the complete official three.js-demo. The objmtl-loader works fine. With the original models.

But if I create a new file in blender, import the original obj-model (from the demo), then add a simple cone and export it again to obj, on my demo-page everything will be shown except my cone.

I compared every simple param (cone <-> imported model) - no difference.

[My demo-page](http://webgl.pauly.io/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html)

[My blender-file](http://webgl.pauly.io/obj/self/testcube.blend)

What do I have to do to get a render-able obj-model-export from blender?

(I tried multiple file formats, but for my usecase Wavefront (obj) is the best)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't post the content of my .blend-file (can I?). The code of my demo-page is just the default-threejs-javascript, where my .obj is loaded. [link] (http://webgl.pauly.io/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html) I think the problem is my blender-file...

Comment: Your cone isn't triangulated (at least at the bottom), that would be my first thought. You can select cone, toggle edit mode, select all, and Ctrl + T or Mesh > Faces > Triangulate faces to fix it. Or select Triangulate faces on OBJ export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it must be something with your Blender export.

Not sure how they play exactly but changing these settings in Blender, I can see your Cone:

- In Export > Wavefront, check `Objects as OJB Groups`
- Select the Cone, Edition mode, `Make Normals Consistent`

I understand the first change the type of the Cone from Object3D to Mesh, and the second let the texture to be placed on it.

Hope it helps

Comment: It's hard to believe - I did exactly what you asked me to do. But the cone is still invisible. I created a new file with the following tutorial and exported it with your params - now it works! So, thank you very much!!! [Tutorial](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Koilz/13.03.15_wiki_-_2.6_Texture_a_Dice)